Given a system of (in)equations, can we find if there is a group that satisfies them?
Given a set of variables $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$, a set of equations based on some group operation $\circ$ over them (something like $x_1 \circ x_2 = x_3$, and a set of inequations over them (something like $x_4 \circ x_5 \neq x_6$), is there an algorithm to determine if there is some group $(G,\circ)$ such that we can find an assignment $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}\subseteq G$ that satisfies these equations and inequations?  It is permitted for variables to be assigned to the same group element.
Does the algorithm change if we demand that $(G,\circ)$ be a finite or Abelian group?  Can we find the smallest group for which the system of (in)equations can be solved?

See group presentation for an introduction to the equational subset of this problem.  Note that just deciding if the group given by a presentation is finite is undecidable.

The difference to the presentation is that the group is allowed to satisfy equations that are not given in the equation set.  E.g. if no inequations are given, the group of one element is always a solution.

I'm not disagreeing ... but the equational subset is generically too hard to handle, and this subset is in your problem class.

@EricTowers.  The quantors are different: for the word problem, we ask if for all groups satisfying the relations the two given words are equal, whereas for my problem we ask if there exists a group that satisfies all the equations.  Likewise, the undecidable problem you linked is “are all groups satisfying these relations finite?”
Whereas I would like to know “is there a finite group satisfying these (in)equations?”
That sounds weaker to me.

What the comments are getting at is that the case with exactly one inequation is closely related to the word problem: let $G$ be the group with presentation where the generators are $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and the relations are the equations.  Then if the inequation holds in $G$ then $G$ is an example.  On the other hand, if the inequation is false in $G$ then pretty much by the universal property of a group with given presentation, that inequation is also false in every group satisfying the equations.

@DanielSchepler Hm yeah I guess that makes sense.  Now one more problem to think about is that I don't have a way to mention inverses in these equations, but there is probably a way to still make it undecidable.

Your "equations" are just relations in a group presentation; at least one group satisfying them always exists. Your "inequations" are words in this group presentation you don't want to be the identity: this is the word problem, and as already mentioned, is undecidable in general. There is a subtlety here that a presentation defines the "free-est" group satisfying your equations. But if an inequation does not hold in this free-est group, then it doesn't hold in any group satisfying your equations, so it's enough to work in a single group.

Oh, I guess I missed that your equations couldn't involve inverses.  But that's not that serious, since you could introduce variables $y_n$ and add equations $x_n y_n = e$ (or $x_n y_n x_n = x_n$ if you also disallow identity in the equations).

There cannot be an algorithm (even with a restriction on "finite"), because of the insolvability of the word problem: (There cannot be an algorithm that tests whether a presentation defines a group that is not trivial. Taking your problem description we could simply take the same presentation and add one-by-one inequalities testing for any of the generators not being the identity. Iff any of them succeeds the original presentation defines a nontrivial group, thus solving the unsolvable problem.)
There are heuristic methods that often work in practice.
"The smallest" does not make sense, as it does not need to be unique.
In the case of abelian groups, it basically reduces to Smith normal form calculations, and thus is polynomial time.

I'm not sure if this is equal to the word problem.  Unlike with the word problem, I'm okay with a group that satisfies relations that do not follow from the equations given.  For example, if no inequations are given, the one element group is always a solution, assigning all variables to the neutral element.

@FUZxxl I added a remark why it is because of the word problem

Thank you all.  I now understand this problem a lot better.
